`LongPressGesture` not registering on iOS 18
I'm on Xcode 16 beta + iOS 18 following Apple's example on LongPressGesture with:
import SwiftUI

struct LongPressGestureView: View {
    @GestureState private var isDetectingLongPress = false
    @State private var completedLongPress = false

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(self.isDetectingLongPress ?
                Color.red :
                (self.completedLongPress ? Color.green : Color.blue))
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 3)
                .onChanged { value in
                    print("onChanged: \(value)")
                }
                .updating($isDetectingLongPress) {
                    currentState, gestureState, transaction in
                    print("currentState: \(currentState)")
                    print("gestureState: \(gestureState)")
                    print("transaction: \(transaction)")
                    gestureState = currentState
                    transaction.animation = Animation.easeIn(duration: 2.0)
                }
                .onEnded { finished in
                    print("finished: \(finished)")
                    self.completedLongPress = finished
                })
    }
}

The circle is suppose to animate from blue to red then turn green when finished, but it's never red for me. I see it turn green and print finished: true when it ends but I don't ever see any of the other print statements.
Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?

Could not make Apple example work either, seems to be old code that does not work anymore.
To achieve what you want you could try this approach:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LongPressGestureView()
    }
}

struct LongPressGestureView: View {
    @State private var isDetectingLongPress = false
    @State private var completedLongPress = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(isDetectingLongPress ? Color.red : (completedLongPress ? Color.green : Color.blue))
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2) {
                completedLongPress = true
            } onPressingChanged: { inProgress in
                isDetectingLongPress = inProgress
            }
    }
}


It seems that if I move my finger the tiniest bit while pressing, the gesture won't complete. Is that expected?

Ok, try this .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2, maximumDistance: xxx) {...}, where you can chosexxx, a maximum distance that the interaction can move before the gesture fails.

Great. Thanks for your help :)

This works, but doesn't allow for simultaneous gestures. Hope Apple can fix this soon.
